# javascript or jquery change different Images on different button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have five buttons when I click on one button one image comes in a div tag again when I click on second button     another image should replace that image with a new one and so on. what code should I write to achieve it.

please help me do that. may it be javascript or jquery. I think something to do with onclick event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple as below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        $('button').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var imgSRC = $(this).data('src');

            $('#image').html('<img src="'+imgSRC+'" alt="" />');
        });

    });
</script>

<button data-src="image1.jpg">One</button>
<button data-src="image1.jpg">Second</button>
<button data-src="image1.jpg">Third</button>
<button data-src="image1.jpg">Fourth</button>
<button data-src="image1.jpg">Fifth</button>

<div id="image"></div>
```

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dipeshbeckham/Ku5pP/1/)**

Comment: yep this is exactly what I wanted. thanks@Dipesh Parmar

Comment: ok what default jquery file I should use. I have used 1.9.1

Comment: @Phpdeveloper jQuery 1.9 is all that you need

Answer (score 2):

```
         <div class="imageSelector" />


  $(".btnOne").on("click", function(){

  $(".imageSelector").html("put here the html code of the image")

  })


  $(".btnTwo").....
```

Answer (score 0):

OldImage value by default set the first image url and in function NewImage url of new image will be occur which may be id of button..

```
var oldImage="img.png";
function ImageChange(NewImage)
{
    $("#divId").replace(oldImage,"newImage");
    oldImage=newImage;
}
```